# App loads a wrong screen before loading the correct screen

Tags: flutter, dart

In my flutter app, I have two screens namely, **AppUpdate** and **StoreTiming**. The **AppUpdate** screen is shown if the current build is not equal to enforced build (See code below). If current build is equal to enforced build, then the **StoreTiming** screen is shown. In the case of current build = enforced build, when I start the app, I see the **AppUpdate** screen appear for about a second and then it is replaced by **StoreTming** screen. Why does this happen?

```
 void initState(){ 
         super.initState();
        _initPackageInfo();
        _enforcedVersion();
    }

    Future<void> _initPackageInfo() async {
        final info = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        setState(() {
          _packageInfo = info;
        });
      }

 
    Future<void> _enforcedVersion() async {
      final RemoteConfig remoteConfig =  RemoteConfig.instance;
      await remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(
                  fetchTimeout: const Duration(seconds: 10),
                  minimumFetchInterval: Duration.zero,
                ));
      await remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate();
       setState(() {
         enforcedBuildNumber = remoteConfig.getString('enforced_build_number');
        });
    }
    
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return !(_isLoading)?MultiProvider(
  providers: [], 
 child: Consumer<Auth>(builder: (ctx, auth, _) => 
      MaterialApp( 
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,    
    title: 'MyAppName',
    theme: ThemeData(
       textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
        bodyColor: Colors.black,
        displayColor: Colors.black,
        ),
      primaryColor:  Colors.white,
      accentColor:  Color(0xFFF2AD18),
      fontFamily: 'Muli',
    ),
    home:    
          _packageInfo.buildNumber!=enforcedBuildNumber?AppUpdateScreen():StoreTimings(),

    routes:{}, 
    ),)):Center(child:Loading());}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you make `_initPackageInfo();` and `_enforcedVersion();` async and async functions need time to complete their works! So before set a correct value on fields in this function `build` method called and show a page. you can await this function before load completely and set correct values then show a page. but while a async functions is doing their own job you must show some thing to user! You can show loading page if you want and if values are ready show a page...
I recommend you to use a state management library like flutter_bloc to have a clean code and better functionallity.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knw this package existed.